# HTML5 cc_load_policy=1 What am I doing wrong?

Tags: youtube-api

I have tired all the iframe and URLs that I came across while searching for an answer.  I did see a post where YouTube support was quoted HTML5 ignores cc_load_policy parameter but that conflicted with what I found on the dev site that states AS3 and HTML5 support this parameter. Using this code for the dev video works - autostarts and displays the closed captions.  When I use another video that has closed captions it doesn't show them.

This works

```
<iframe width="420" height="345"src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?cc_load_policy=1&autoplay=1"></iframe>
```

I updated the video ID with another video that has closed captions but they DO NOT display.

```
<iframe width="420" height="345"src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/0F87rB0c6Is?cc_load_policy=1&autoplay=1"></iframe>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When I use captions.list for the second video, it says that the captions are ASR (automatic speech recognition). Maybe that's why the captions don't display. Have you tried it with another video that has ASR captions?